# How to fetch information from a website, similar to how it is done in Facebook?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

When we add a URL to a Facebook comment, it automatically fetches some information about the website, and, most of the time, the relevant information. I want to make a similar functionality for my site.

I am using Rails 3.0.3. Could you please suggest me a good gem or the mechanism to do this?

Comment: Try to build it yourself instead. And if you'll have questions about actual programming, then come back here.

Comment: @theTinMan the level of English in this post is fine. That was rude and unnecessary. I've seen worse from native speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook looks for Open Graph metadata, check out this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) it might help you.